# Python - openpyxl - delete multiple tabs if they are in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I'm new to python and I'm trying to convert some VBA used to format excel files into python. I have an excel file with 100 worksheets and I would like to delete the worksheets if they are not in a list. For example, the workbook contains worksheets 'Sheet1', 'Sheet2',...'Sheet100' I would like to delete all tabs if they are not in this list ['Sheet25', 'Sheet50', 'Sheet75', 'Sheet100'].

I'm able to use this code to delete a single worksheet:

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('testdel.xlsx')
delete = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet2')
wb.remove_sheet(delete)  
wb.save('testdel2.xlsx')
```

I've attempted this code to delete multiple sheets / and or a single sheet but I can't seem to get it to work. Any suggestions on how to modify so that is will delete all sheets if they are not in a list? Thanks in advance for your help!

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('testdel.xlsx')
ws = wb.get_sheet_names()
if ws is not ['Sheet25', 'Sheet50', 'Sheet75', 'Sheet100']:
    wb.remove_sheet(ws)
wb.save('testdel2.xlsx')`
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you're confusing worksheet names with worksheet objects. `wb.remove_sheet()` needs to be passed an existing sheet. However, it's easier just to use `del wb[sheetName]`

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('testdel.xlsx')

keep_sheets = ['Sheet25', 'Sheet50', 'Sheet75', 'Sheet100']
for sheetName in wb.sheetnames:
    if sheetName not in keep_sheets:
        del wb[sheetName]
wb.save('testdel2.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('testdel.xlsx')
ws = wb.get_sheet_names()
for sheetName in ws:
    if sheetName not in ['Sheet25', 'Sheet50', 'Sheet75', 'Sheet100']:
        sheetToDelete = wb.get_sheet_by_name(sheetName) // gets the sheet object
        wb.remove_sheet(sheetToDelete)
wb.save('testdel2.xlsx')
```